# javascript - optimizing loop through very long select

Tags: javascript

I have 2 select boxes, one with possible choices, the other with selections. User selects from the first, then presses a button which copies them to the second. if I have 7500 options in the first, and I select them all, it takes approx. this amount of time to copy them all to the second select (on my pc):

```
IE v11 : ~3 minutes
Chrome v65: ~2 minutes
Firefox (latest): ~7 seconds (not a typo)
```

In an effort to improve the time, I tried breaking up into chunks of copying 150 at a time but it didn't help. The loop is this (below). Here I am stopping at a max = 150 and recursively calling it again. but original loop went to the end of the select. not much faster than what I have.
Does anyone have any ideas to optimize it to get more reasonable response on Chrome, IE?

```
// o_col = originating select, d_col = target select.
copyOptionAddPrefixRecursive:function(o_col, d_col, prefix, destTabId,  
badgeId, startingIndex, max) {
// same as copyOptionAddPrefix but it is recursive and has a max # of options to copy.
  var cntr = 0;
  var i;
  for (i=startingIndex;i<document.form1[o_col].length && cntr < max;i++) {
    if (document.form1[o_col].options[i].selected==true) {
      oText = document.form1[o_col].options[i].innerHTML;
      if (prefix) oText = prefix + ' ' + oText;
      oValue = document.form1[o_col].options[i].value;
      //document.form1[d_col].options[document.form1[d_col].length] = new     Option (oText, oValue, false, selectedBool);
      var newOpt = new Option (oText, oValue, false, false);
      newOpt.title = oText;
      newOpt.text = null;
      newOpt.innerHTML = oText;
      document.form1[d_col].options[document.form1[d_col].length] = newOpt;
      document.form1[o_col].options[i].selected=false;
      cntr++;
    }
  }
  var selTotal = $('#xtabDemos1 :selected').length;
  if (selTotal) {
    var cmd = 'addressBook.copyOptionAddPrefixRecursive(\"' + o_col  + '\",\"' + d_col + '\",';
    if (prefix && prefix != null) cmd += '\"' + prefix + '\"';
    else  cmd += prefix;
    cmd +=  ',\"' + destTabId + '\",\"' + badgeId + '\",' + i + ',' + max  + ');';
    setTimeout(cmd, 50); // run cmd after 50 ms.
  } else {
    $('.nav-tabs a[href="' + '#' + destTabId + '"]').tab('show');
    updateBadge(document.getElementsByName(d_col)[0], badgeId);
  }
```

and here is a sample of the select. I had thought the problem was the onchange being called in both selects within the loop but I added console.log() linesto the onchange function and it does not seem to get called.

```
<select class="form-control my_select" onchange="checkAdjacentRow('DEMOS_LIST_XTAB');" 
multiple="" name="DEMOS_LIST_XTAB" id="xtabDemos1" style="height:100%;">
<option value="(181124 ! 181134)" title="TOOTHPASTE; Baking Soda (6m)">TOOTHPASTE; Baking Soda (6m)</option>
<option value="(181125 ! 181135)" title="TOOTHPASTE; Non Baking Soda (6m)">TOOTHPASTE; Non Baking Soda (6m)</option>
<option value="(181126 ! 181136)" title="TOOTHPASTE; Tartar Control (6m)">TOOTHPASTE; Tartar Control (6m)</option>
<option value="(181127 ! 181137)" title="TOOTHPASTE; Regular (Not Tartar Control) (6m)">TOOTHPASTE; Regular (Not Tartar Control) (6m)</option> 
</select>
```

and the target select:

```
<select class="form-control my_select mySelectionsSelects" onchange="checkAdjacentRow('DEMOS_SELECTED_XTAB_COLS');" multiple="" name="DEMOS_SELECTED_XTAB_COLS" id="demosXtabCols">
</select>
```

Comment: I'd worry more about user experience at that point. 7,500 is too many choices without a filter

Answer (score 0):

While you should never have 7500 `options` in a `select` box, and I can't imagine why you would want to copy the contents of one `select` to another, and I haven't tested the performance, it would be easier to simply copy the `innerHTML`:

```
let mySelects = document.querySelectorAll('.my_select');
let firstSelect = mySelects[0];
let secondSelect = mySelects[1];

secondSelect.innerHTML = firstSelect.innerHTML;
```

Comment: The page mimicks a desktop app which, at times, displays lists that long. Cant break it up unless I have to.  I am only copying their selections. Some users select the whole select contents.